# How do I execute an exec resource if a service on windows exists or not?

Tags: puppet

I want to execute an exec resource if a service is not found, skip the exec resource if the service is found.  Here is my attempt:

```
exec { 'Executing SplunkForwarder Installation Script':
  command => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\Apps\windows_splunkforwarder_deploy.ps1',
  onlyif  => if(Get-Service SplunkForwarder) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 },
  provider => powershell,
  }
```

If the code is executed correctly it should skip the exec resource if the service is found and execute the resource if it is not found.

Comment: So are you saying that the resource you've presented does not work as you would like?  In that case, in what way and under what circumstances does it fail?

Comment: here is the error:
```Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Resource type not found: SplunkForwarder (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/rol
e/manifests/windows_splunk_universal_forwarder.pp, line: 45, column: 36) on node testpc```
Line 45 is the onlyif line

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows or services.  You forgot to quote the `onlyif` parameter, which should be a single string.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can look into is the "creates" property in exec. This property will only trigger the command to run if a certain file doesn't exist. You would want your code to look something like this:

```
exec { 'Executing SplunkForwarder Installation Script':
  command  => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\Apps\windows_splunkforwarder_deploy.ps1',
  creates  => 'C:/Program Files/SplunkForwarder',
  provider => powershell,
}
```

If you have any further questions about the exec resource, you can look at the documentation Puppet has here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-creates